# Deleting related objects fails sometimes

Tags: django, django-models

I have Models like this:

```
class Server(Model):
  ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()                           
  hostname = models.CharField()
  contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
  note = models.ForeignKey(Note)

class Contact(Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  dept = models.CharField()

class Note(Model):
  subject = models.CharField()
  body = models.CharField()
```

Also I have this post_delete handler:

```
# When deleting a Server, if the Server's Contact doesn't                              
# reference another Server delete the Contact. Also, do the same
# for note. This ensures no orphaned contacts or notes left in database.

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Server)
def delete_contact_note(sender, instance, **kwargs):
if not Server.objects.filter(contact=instance.contact):
    instance.contact.delete()
if not Server.objects.filter(note=instance.note):
    instance.note.delete()
```

The problem happens when deleting several Server objects in one go via admin - it fails in the post_delete call with the following message:

```
DoesNotExist: Contact matching query does not exist.
```

It's as if the Contact object has been deleted before the Server object?

If I try to delete one Server object at a time (again via admin) it works. It only seems to happen if I am deleting a lot of objects at once.

What's causing this?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try to use try/expect:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Server)
def delete_contact_note(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        if not Server.objects.filter(contact=instance.contact):
            instance.contact.delete()
        if not Server.objects.filter(note=instance.note):
            instance.note.delete()
    expect ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass  # U can change this command
```

*This is not solution, just this snippet help it. But you can catch all object ;)*